# JavaScript setTimeout() in Chrome console

Tags: javascript

Why `setTimeout` doesn't work from Chrome console on some pages or what am I doing wrong?

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log('a');},3000);
```

output:

`<- 6425`

Example page: http://olx.pl

---

EDIT: Seems that on some pages `console.log()` is being overridden ... as it's site specific problem, this question should be deleted. But can't do that, as it has answers.

Comment: [`window.setTimeout()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Comment: why you down vote my question when there is no answer for that in documentation?

Comment: The number `6425` is the timeout id. So clearly it is at least creating the timeout. In 3 seconds, it should call the function. So why would it not show the log? Well is your console filtered to not show log lines?

Comment: Why? because it also outputs the string `"a"`

Comment: but it does not!! anybody pasted my code to the console and checked it out before down vote?

Comment: LOL.... it works....

Comment: outputs "a" after 3 seconds?

Comment: No it outputs "a" after 3 seconds.

Comment: It does not. What browser version you got?

Comment: Dude your browser has an issue. Do you have your console logs filtered to not show console.log ? If you change it to alert() does the alert appear?

Comment: check yourself on page: http://olx.pl - it does not work! But it works on StackOverflow... what the...?

Comment: wow now everyone stays quiet ... alert appears.

Comment: It means your problem is somewhere else in your code and it's not our fault you didn't formulate your question properly.

Comment: I didn't because I had no idea that site may be a problem, but edited it as soon as I noticed it.

Comment: What happens if you simply do `console.log("a")` in the console?

Comment: works... but `window.console.log("a")` does not (but is defined)...  seems that it have been overridden...

Comment: Well... the problem seems to be site specific. Can't delete question myself as it has answers (that are wrong in my case). Voted to close the question, as I can't delete it.

Answer (score 3):

It does work. The catch is you may not be waiting enough.

```js
console.log(setTimeout(() => console.log('a'), 1000));
```

That number you get is the `timeoutId`. Anytime you call `setTimeout` or `setInterval` it returns a numeric ID which you can then pass to `clearTimeout()` or `clearInterval()` to abort it before it runs.

Comment: doesn't work for me, even when waiting a minute. please run your code from console... you will see it does not work.

Comment: @FlashThunder perhaps there is a console.log override on that site